# Where to declare the shared variables in an object oriented design in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop

```
class B
{
    // This will run in the thread
    void run();
};

class A
{
    // This will run in the thread
    void run();
};

class Thread_manager
{
    A objA;
    B objB;

    // This class will start the threads.
};
```

The shared variable is a vector of struct.

One way is to make it global. I want to know according to OOP where should the shared variables be declared in an object oriented design in C++?

Comment: I don't think there is a single OO answer :) There are a lot of ways of doing that.

Comment: @Rakete1111 what are those lots of ways?

Comment: Off the top of my head, store a ref to it in `A` and `B`, global, ... But maybe there's a better way that I didn't think of, which is why this isn't an answer :)

Comment: Basically, the lowest child in a class hierarchy which have all the information needed for creation/destruction of a shared object should manage that object. In your case it probably an instance of the `Thread_manager` class, but it also could be an instance of it's parent/owner/creator class

Comment: Be aware that a vector is not thread save. You have to guard access to it inside each thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many options. If you manage threads by `ThreadManager`, its instance could be a good place for a shared state. For example:

```
struct SharedState {
   std::vector<int> v;
};

class A { 
   public: 
      void run(SharedState* state) { std::cout << state->v.size() << std::endl; }
};

class ThreadManager {
   public:
      ThreadManager() : state_(new SharedState{}) { state_->v.resize(10); }

      void run_threads() {
         threads_.emplace_back(&A::run, &a_, state_.get());
      }

      void finish_threads() {
         for (auto & t : threads_) t.join();
      }

   private:
      std::unique_ptr<SharedState> state_;
      std::vector<std::thread> threads_;
      A a_;
};

int main() {
   ThreadManager tm;
   tm.run_threads();
   tm.finish_threads();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like all variables, you should declare shared variables in the narrowest scope which has the data to initialise them and also the lifetime that they need.

Lacking any additional context, a reasonable default is

```
class B
{
    SharedData & shared;

public:
    B(SharedData & shared) : shared(shared) {}
    void run();
};

class A
{
    SharedData & shared;

public:
    A(SharedData & shared) : shared(shared) {}
    void run();
};

class Thread_manager
{
    SharedData shared;
    A objA;
    B objB;
    std::thread threadA;
    std::thread threadB;

public:
    Thread_manager() 
     : objA(shared), 
       objB(shared), 
       threadA(&A::run, &objA), 
       threadB(&B::run, &objB)
    {}

    ~Thread_manager()
    {
        threadA.join();
        threadB.join();
    }
};
```

Comment: you have declared shared data variable in both A and B classes. It is supposed to be shared. Why declare at both places? Please explain.

Comment: I have declared a *reference* to shared data in both `A` and `B`, which is *bound* to the same object (which *in the case* of `objA` and `objB` is a member of `Thread_manager`)

Comment: yes, but why pass it in the constructor? This shared variable will be a vector which can be appended with data by other class. You also mean that because of it being a reference it will always have the updated value?

Comment: There is **only one** object of type `SharedData` per `Thread_manager` in this example. It has *three names*, at most one of which is accessible at any time.

Comment: how is passing them in the constructors of A and B helpful? please explain.

Comment: You have to initialise a reference member in the constructor (specifically in the member initialiser list, the part between `:` and `{`).

Comment: As in, `class CannotBeCreated { int & reference_member; }` cannot have any instances, because it has a private reference, and no way to bind that reference to an object.

Comment: And I am assuming that the `SharedData` is relevant for the whole lifetime of the `A` and the `B`. If you have `void A::run_with_shared(SharedData &)`, you can start a `std::thread otherAThread(&A::run_with_shared, std::ref(shared));`